# CSS Transitioning issue

Tags: css, tabs, hover, transition

I'm trying to get tabs (as a menu) to be offset the screen and when somebody hovers over it, it transitions downwards revealing more of the tab.  My code is this:

```
.tab:hover {
    position: relative; 
    top: 45px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

When I hover over the image, it does the transitioning downwards correctly.  However, when I leave the tab, it snaps back into place.  What I'd like it to do is transition back into its original place, not snap.  What am I missing from the code to make this happen?

**UPDATE:**

I figured out the problem.  I made a new CSS style set for just `.tab` and I put in the transitioning AND `top: 0px`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting it on the `:hover`, put the `transition` on `.tab`.